# form validation with data ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate HTML form. check a field with two other relative range fields. I want to check all variables `isset` and between the range before submitting form.
I tried this method not giving the expected result.
How can I do it with other easiest method.

```js
$("#form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var apple = $('.apple').val();
var aFirst = $('.aFirst').val();
var aLast = $('.aLast').val();

var banana = $('.banana').val();
var bFirst = $('.bFirst').val();
var bLast = $('.bLast').val();

var orange = $('.orange').val();
var oFirst = $('.oFirst').val();
var oLast = $('.oLast').val();
if(apple >= aFirst && apple <= aLast){
    var a = 'true';
}else{
  var a = 'false';
}
if(banana >= bFirst && banana <= bLast){
    var b = 'true';
}else{
  var b = 'false';
}
if(orange >= oFirst && orange <= oLast){
    var o = 'true';
}else{
  var o = 'false';
}

if(a == 'true' && b == 'true' && o == 'true')
{
  alert('success');
  //do ajax
}else{
  alert('error');
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Apple Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="apple" placeholder="Type between 15-25">
            <input type="hidden" class="aFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="aLast" value="20">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Banana Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="banana" placeholder="Type between 10-20">
            <input type="hidden" class="bFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="bLast" value="20">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Orange Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="orange" placeholder="Type between 10-20">
            <input type="hidden" class="oFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="oLast" value="20">
    </div>
   <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: There is a `.aFirst` in js and in html the class is `qFirst` same for `.aSecond`

Comment: From a stylistic point of view, declare the variables once as false, then set them true if the value is valid. Also, use actual Boolean values rather than strings.

Comment: @Kenny sorry i removed these typos.

Comment: What's the problem? What is the expected result that you are not getting? Once you fixed the typo, the code as presented here appears to work as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden input classes for apples should be `aFirst` and `aLast`:

**Update**: I have corrected the following line:

`<input type="hidden" class="aLast" value="25">`

**Update 2**: Works when fruit divs are removed. + Cleanup.

```js
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var apple = $('.apple').val();
        var aFirst = $('.aFirst').val();
        var aLast = $('.aLast').val();

        var banana = $('.banana').val();
        var bFirst = $('.bFirst').val();
        var bLast = $('.bLast').val();

        var orange = $('.orange').val();
        var oFirst = $('.oFirst').val();
        var oLast = $('.oLast').val();

        var a = true;
        var b = true;
        var o = true;

        if (apple == "" || apple < aFirst || apple > aLast) {
            a = false;
        }
        if (banana == "" || banana < bFirst || banana > bLast) {
            b = false;
        }
        if (orange == "" || orange < oFirst || orange > oLast) {
            o = false;
        }

        if (a && b && o) {
            alert('success');
            //do ajax
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Banana Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="banana" placeholder="Type between 10-20">
            <input type="hidden" class="bFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="bLast" value="20">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Orange Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="orange" placeholder="Type between 10-20">
            <input type="hidden" class="oFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="oLast" value="20">
    </div>
   <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: The answer has been updated (the value was incorrectly 20).

Comment: If any of these fields (fruits) are hidden or not defined in html then it should return as true in js.

Comment: Do you mean that the validation should allow empty fruit fields?

Comment: not a field i mean if remove a complete div containing apple and its ranges then it should return as true in js validation. currently its returning error.

Comment: To confirm: Validation should fail if a fruit field is empty, but it should succeed if the fruit div is removed?

Comment: Yes, if a fruit field exist it should validate otherwise success.

Comment: it was giving error until I added Number() function copied from @Kenny answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo,

you have a class name as `qFirst` and `qLast` in HTML and js you have written `.aFirst` and `.aLast`.

Also convert all values to `Number`.

When you do `.val()`, it returns `string`. And Comparing Strings can give unexpected results

```js
$("#form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var apple = Number($('.apple').val());
var aFirst = Number($('.aFirst').val());
var aLast = Number($('.aLast').val());

var banana = Number($('.banana').val());
var bFirst = Number($('.bFirst').val());
var bLast = Number($('.bLast').val());

var orange = Number($('.orange').val());
var oFirst = Number($('.oFirst').val());
var oLast = Number($('.oLast').val());
if(apple >= aFirst && apple <= aLast){
    var a = 'true';
}else{
  var a = 'false';
}
if(banana >= bFirst && banana <= bLast){
    var b = 'true';
}else{
  var b = 'false';
}
if(orange >= oFirst && orange <= oLast){
    var o = 'true';
}else{
  var o = 'false';
}

if(a == 'true' && b == 'true' && o == 'true')
{
  alert('success');
  //do ajax
}else{
  alert('error');
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Apple Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="apple" placeholder="Type between 15-25">
            <input type="hidden" class="aFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="aLast" value="25">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Banana Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="banana" placeholder="Type between 10-20">
            <input type="hidden" class="bFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="bLast" value="20">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Orange Price:</label>
            <input type="number" class="orange" placeholder="Type between 10-20">
            <input type="hidden" class="oFirst" value="10">
            <input type="hidden" class="oLast" value="20">
    </div>
   <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: And if any of these fields (fruits) are hidden or not defined in html then should I use `isset`  with variables like `if(isset(apple) && apple >= aFirst && apple <= aLast)`?

Comment: There no function is javascript called `isset`. You can do something like this `if(apple && apple >= aFirst && apple <= aLast)`

Comment: `if (apple)` will return `false` if `apple` value is `undefined` or `''`